# Getting rid of padding?

Tags: html, css

How do I get rid of all of this white space so everything will touch each other?
I'm building a site for a friend for free just for the exp. So yes, I know it looks novice. Here is everything:

http://jsfiddle.net/e2p3pwtb/embedded/result/

```
h1{
    background-image: url(silver-955496_960_720.jpg);
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

#mainnav{ background-image: url(silver-313347_960_720.jpg);}

body {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}



.sidebar1{
    float:left;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 0 20px 0 10px;
    background-image: url(silver-955496_960_720.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    height:650px;}

.main{
   float: left;
    width: 60%;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
    background-image: url(silver-313347_960_720.jpg);}




.sidebar2{
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 0 10px 0 20px;
     background-image: url(silver-955496_960_720.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    height:650px;}


/*This will keep you from having "float drops"*/
*{box-sizing: border-box;}
```

Comment: Which white space are you talking about? how exactly do you want the site to look like.

Comment: You might want to start off with an HTML reset, such as http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/

Comment: Which space? As first sight, the body element has text-align: center;, so you have all the elements with centered content making spaces within each container.

Comment: Are you talking about just the sidebars, main body, etc?

Comment: You can use [normalize css](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/normalize) to reset browser styles. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/e2p3pwtb/2/).

Comment: Please elaborate more detail or share an image. Otherwise this question has many answers and you might get downvotes.

Comment: I may have answered too soon. If you _really_ want everything to be touching, you also need to remove the padding you put in the stylesheet; I'm not sure if that's what you want. As an extreme example, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/e2p3pwtb/3/). So yes, maybe some elaboration is in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some elements have margins by default. In your fiddle, add

```css
h1, p, ul {margin:0}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/e2p3pwtb/1/

Or, more thorough,

```css
* {margin:0}
```

which I can't really recommend though. Things like that change the appearance too much from its natural state.